# Binding Settings based SolidColorBrush directly in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Given a `Settings.settings` file that contains one or more `SolidColorBrush` entries on it with `Application` scope, how can I bind these values to XAML style templates?

For instance, I'll have a `SolidColorBrush` named `MyAppColor` with `#FF0091D2` as value and a custom `Button` style template, where I want the `Background` to have the color from `MyAppColor`. How can I achieve this?

---

I have already tried adding a *`namespace (?)`* to the xaml file, like this:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:namespace.Properties"
```

Then tried to use the `properties` like this:

```
Background="{x:Static properties:Settings.Default.MyAppColor}"
```

But it says it can't have nested types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while `Settings.Default` is static, `MyAppColor` property isn't. (Settings.Default is a Singletone effectively). Use {x:Static} extension to set `Binding.Source` and provide `Binding.Path` as usual:

```
Background="{Binding Path=MyAppColor, Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}}"
```